# Are realpath() portability concerns obsolete?

Tags: unix, posix, portability, realpath

The traditional way to call the Unix `realpath()` function has been `realpath(pathname, buf)` where `buf` is a user-supplied buffer with room for `PATH_MAX` bytes. This is problematic since `PATH_MAX` is unnecessarily big for most filenames and yet can be smaller than the actual OS pathname length limit.

The ability to pass a `NULL` pointer in place of `buf` was later added. In this case `realpath()` will dynamically allocate a buffer of the right size using `malloc()`. This makes the function easy to use safely. Since `NULL` support was a later addition, it was not universally implemented and hence portable programs could not rely on it.

[POSIX Issue 7, 2018 edition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realpath.html) now guarantees `NULL`  support. Endorsement by POSIX would seem to imply that the portability concerns have all but vanished. Are there any Unix systems in active use (e.g. from the last decade) where `realpath()` does not  support giving a `NULL` buffer?

Answer (score 1):

`realpath(path, NULL)` works on recent releases of at least the following systems:

- Darwin
- DragonFly BSD
- FreeBSD
- Haiku
- Linux/glibc
- Linux/musl
- Minix
- NetBSD
- OpenBSD
- Solaris (OmniOS)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Gnulib documentation](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob;f=doc/posix-functions/realpath.texi), the Gnulib developers last saw this issue on

- Mac OS X 10.5 (end of support in 2011),
- FreeBSD 6.4 (end of support in 2010),
- OpenBSD 4.4 (end of support in 2009),
- Solaris 10 (end of support **in 2024**).